# Почему «test» не срабатывает на параметре функции: if [ -n $1 ]; then ...?

Tags: linux, bash

Почему `test` не срабатывает на параметре функции:

```
myFunc() {
    if [ -n $1 ]; then
        echo 'TRUE'
        return
    fi
    echo 'FALSE'
}

myFunc 123 # TRUE

myFunc # TRUE
```

Во втором случае я ожидал увидеть `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если переменной `var` не присвоено никакое значение, то оператор

```
[ -n $var ]
```

будет эквивалентен оператору

```
[ -n ]
```

который всегда возвращает «истину» (`0`) в качестве кода возврата.

---

если требуется, чтобы в такой ситуации код возврата был «ложь» (ненулевое значение), обращение к переменной надо заключить в двойные кавычки:

```
[ -n "$var" ]
```

собственно, так всегда лучше делать, потому что если переменная `var` содержит, например, пробел, то выполнение оператора вызовет программную ошибку:

```
$ var="x y"
$ [ -n $var ]; echo $?
bash: [: x: binary operator expected
2
```

а с кавычками выполнится корректно:

```
$ unset var
$ [ -n "$var" ]; echo $?
1
```

```
$ var=
$ [ -n "$var" ]; echo $?
1
```

```
$ var=x
$ [ -n "$var" ]; echo $?
0
```

```
$ var="x y"
$ [ -n "$var" ]; echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что оператор `-n` оперирует **строкой**; следовательно параметр `$1` должен быть заключён в **двойные** кавычки (при одинарных он не будет  вычислен, то есть будет фигурировать как есть):

```
myFunc() {
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        echo 'TRUE'
        return
    fi
    echo 'FALSE'
}

myFunc 123 # TRUE

myFunc # FALSE
```